# Does abortion decrease fertility rate?

Tags: medical-science

I see many website make this claim but I cannot find any scientific articles that support this claim.

I know that certain complications like pelvic inflammatory disease (PID) damage to the womb (uterus) can affect fertility afterwards but what are the actual statics.

Also my mother is making a claim that she has read scientific articles that having an abortion during first pregnancy is especially damaging to later fertility rates.

I did a google search but could not find anything at all that would support her claim.

So Does having an abortion really significantly decreases fertility rates? Does having an abortion first time you are pregnant decreases fertility rates?

Comment: First 3 hits in a [Google search](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=abortion+decreases+fertility&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=E-W-VeKJM8yfugSHkrqYBA) all link to respectable sources saying that it usually does not.

Comment: Fertility rate is a funny quantity, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_fertility_rate. Maybe the question should be rephrased to "Does an abortion decrease fertility?".

Answer (score 2):

http://www.nhs.uk/chq/Pages/1645.aspx?CategoryID=60

**So Does having an abortion really significantly decreases fertility rates?**

The claim does appear to be correct though "significantly" would only be in the statistical sense, ie it does and it's real but the effect is small.

**Does having an abortion first time you are pregnant decreases fertility rates?**

I can find no data on this specific claim.

> In the UK, most women who have an abortion don’t have any
>   complications and their fertility isn’t affected.
>
> However, a small number of women (see below) have complications, such
>   as:
>
> - a severe infection, such as pelvic inflammatory disease (PID)
> - damage to the womb (uterus)
>
> Complications such as these can affect fertility. Also, repeated
>   abortions can cause damage to your cervix and increase the risk of
>   late miscarriages. Infection after an abortion
>
> Taking antibiotics before an abortion may reduce your risk of
>   infection. The healthcare professionals treating you will provide
>   advice about taking antibiotics.
>
> Most infections are easy to treat. However, an infection, such as PID,
>   that’s not treated could lead to a more severe infection of your
>   reproductive organs. This can cause infertility or an ectopic
>   pregnancy (when a fertilised egg implants itself outside the womb).
>   Damage to the womb during an abortion
>
> The risk of damage to the womb during an abortion is low in the UK:
>
> - damage to the cervix (the neck of the womb) occurs in less than 10 in
>     every 1,000 abortions
> - damage to the womb occurs in less than one in 1,000 medical abortions
>     carried out at 12-24 weeks, and up to four in every 1,000
>
> surgical abortions
>
> A medical abortion involves taking medication that causes you to have
>   a miscarriage. A surgical abortion is a procedure to remove the foetus
>   from the womb. Read information about how abortions are performed.
>
> Damage to the cervix can make it weaker. If the cervix can’t stay
>   tightly closed in a future pregnancy (cervical incompetence), this can
>   increase the risk of miscarriage. However, cervical incompetence can
>   be treated with an operation to put a small stitch of strong thread
>   around your cervix to keep it closed.